# python split a string when a keyword comes after a pattern

Tags: python, regex

I have a hostname like

```
ab-test-db-dev.0002-colo1-vm234.abc.domain.com
```

(yeah there is no convention followed internally for hostname.)

I was trying to split this hostname to

```
ab-test-db-dev.0002-colo1-vm234
```

pattern is to split with the '.', but only if there are no other special characters following that dot.

I tried

```
pattern = domain.split(".")
```

but it is taking only till

```
ab-test-db-dev and not ab-test-db-dev.0002-colo1-vm234
```

as the first element.

What is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: Define *no other special characters* here. You mean you want to split off any part of the name that contains dashes and digits?

Comment: You probably want to use `hostname -s`. From `man hostname` --> `Display the short host name. This is the host name cut at the first dot`

Comment: @fedorqui: no, that would give `ab-test-db-dev`. instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could remove the first part until no more dashes remain; that'd be the domain name to remove from the hostname:

```
hostname = domain
while '-' in domain:
    domain = domain.partition('.')[-1]
hostname = hostname[:-len(domain) - 1]
```

or the other way around, remove the last part if it *doesn't* contain dashes, with [`str.rpartition()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.rpartition):

```
hostname = domain
while True:
    first, _, end = hostname.rpartition('.')
    if '-' in end:
        break
    hostname = first
```

Using a regular expression looking for any part that only contains letters and dots:

```
import re

hostname = re.sub(r'\.[a-z.]+$', '', domain)
```

Demo:

```
>>> domain = 'ab-test-db-dev.0002-colo1-vm234.abc.domain.com'
>>> hostname = domain
>>> while '-' in domain:
...     domain = domain.partition('.')[-1]
... 
>>> hostname[:-len(domain) - 1]
'ab-test-db-dev.0002-colo1-vm234'
>>> domain = 'ab-test-db-dev.0002-colo1-vm234.abc.domain.com'
>>> hostname = domain
>>> while True:
...     first, _, end = hostname.rpartition('.')
...     if '-' in end:
...         break
...     hostname = first
... 
>>> hostname
'ab-test-db-dev.0002-colo1-vm234'
>>> import re
>>> re.sub(r'\.[a-z.]+$', '', domain)
'ab-test-db-dev.0002-colo1-vm234'
```

Comment: So there is no way, to split from the last of a string?

Comment: @pkill: Yes, there is, with `str.rpartition()` and `str.rsplit()` with a limit. I'm using the first in my answer.

Comment: Decided to go with the last regex part re.sub. Thanks a lot Martijin.

Answer (score 0):

Didn't get the pattern but for this case the following can work.

```
(?<=\d)\.
```

Try this:

https://regex101.com/r/rU8yP6/21

Use `re.split`.

```
 import re
 re.split(r"(?<=\d)\.",test_Str)
```

Or

```
^(.*?)(?!.*-)\.
```

Try this:

https://regex101.com/r/rU8yP6/22

```
import re
print re.findall(r"^(.*?)(?!.*-)\.",test_str)
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly, then this regex should do the job:

`.*?(?=\.(?!.*[^\w.]))`

```
>>> print re.match(r'.*?(?=\.(?!.*[^\w.]))', 'ab-test-db-dev.0002-colo1-vm234.abc.domain.com')
ab-test-db-dev.0002-colo1-vm234
```

---

Explanation:

```
.*? # match everything up to...
(?=
    \. # the first dot...
    (?! # that isn't followed by...
        .* # any text and...
        [^\w.] # something that's not a word character or a dot.
    )
)
```